# Python 3.4 on windows 7 64 bit: kill a python process

Tags: windows, python-3.4, kill-process

in a python 3.4 script, I've opened a process this way:

```
 myProcess = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, pythonprocess.py, args], shell=False)
```

How can I kill this process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

Comment: @alexwlchan, it's not a duplicate. jul is using `shell=False`. So the child process can be killed simply using `myProcess.kill()`.

Comment: @eryksun oops, how did I miss that. Not a dupe then my bad.